# symfony2: access cookie in rendered controller

Tags: symfony, cookies, render

i'm using symfony2 and i'm experiencing a strange behavior with my cookies. Here's the process :
1- I render a classic form, nothing tricky -> OK
2- I validate the form and i set a cookie to remember the form is ok

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{      
    [...]
    if ($form->isValid()) {     
         [...]
         $cookie = new Cookie('cookietest', 'rdvalue', time()+3600 * 24 * 365, '/', null, false, false);
         $response = new Response();
         $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
         $response->prepare($request);            
         $response->send();

         $formSuccess = true;
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'formSuccess' => $formSuccess);
}
```

All seems to work perfectly at this point. In my rendered index template, i have a rendered controller as follow :

**index.html.twig :**

```
{% if  formSuccess %}
    {{ render(controller('MyBundle:Demo:checkCookie')) }}              
{% endif %}
```

and in my checkCookie action :

```
public function checkCookieAction(Request $request){
     [...]  
     if($request->cookies->has('cookietest')) <-- return false. If i dump it, i don't see the cookietest cookie
     [...]
}
```

I should be able to see the cookie because i set it up in the previous controller, the one which rendered the index.html.twig page.

And even stranger, if i just refresh the page, the `if($request->cookies->has('cookietest'))` line return **true** this time !!

What i've missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jovan Perovic stated, when you are viewing a page for the first time after form submit, you actually haven't cookie, because you just received it with response.

Solution is to redirect after validate the form:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
... 
    $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('actual_route'));
}
```

It's recommended in documentation too:

> Redirecting a user after a successful form submission prevents the user from being able to hit the "Refresh" button of their browser and re-post the data.

Comment: It did the trick, thank you. More info why it's not available in the render function directly ? Doesn't the render function call a new request ?

Comment: I just edited my answer. It's logically explainable, just imagine I'm server, and I shout to you "I'm here", then I don't know if you heard that or no, but when you shout "OK", then I know you heard. (sory for my english)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, this is the way it is supposed to work. Official `PHP`'s docs state this:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also exist in $_REQUEST.

So, I believe your cookie will appear on next request. Am I right?

Comment: yes you right, but i thought the render function fire a request and so the cookie should be available in it. It seems not but don't know exactly why